# Displaying location based content to googlebot and avoiding cloaking

Tags: geolocation, ip, googlebot, cloaking

I have a website that should display different prices for the same item based on the visitors' country.

A visitor from the US sees 10 USD, while one from Germany sees 12 euros.

I do this using visitors' IPs.

However, as Googlebot IP is usually a US IP, it indexes USD prices as well for German pages.

Therefore, I intend to detect Googlebot and have it index Euro prices for German pages.

I wonder if this is perceived as cloaking by Google.